# Batch Calcs.. Not the same as usual

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a desktop binary calculator and can't seem to get values to calculate properly.

http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=mtsJRys8

```
:: functions for 128
if userValue GEQ 128 (
    set bin128 = 1
    goto 64
)
if not userValue GEQ 128 (
    set bin128 = 0
)
```

Trying to get the Variable 'bin128' to end with  a value 1 or 0

Comment: Q: Is there any reason you'd want to do something as perverse as try to write a binary calculator in a .bat file?  As opposed to a "real" language (*any* language)?  Like VBScript, Powershell ... or Perl, Python, Java, C#, etc etc...?

Comment: @paulsm4 Currently not fluent in any 'language' except Batch :( learning VBScript at the moment. sorry :/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please [edit] your question to include your code (or actually, preferably a [mcve]) and precisely what incorrect behavior you're seeing?

Comment: It seems that your program is not a "desktop binary calculator", but just a decimal to binary conversion! When post questions in this forum, try to be as clearer as possible and provide enough details on the problem. Did your code run? It marks any error? What have you tried to fix such error? I think your problem have no relation to a "binary calculator", but to basic Batch file concepts, so perhaps you should reformulate your question. (i.e. "How an `if` command is written in Batch?").

Comment: @paulsm4: We frequently see this type of opinions about Batch files that are carelessly made without any prove. Perhaps you may post a decimal to binary conversion program (that does _not_ use an intrinsic function to do so) written in the "real" programming language of your choice, so we can compare it vs. the Batch file solutions posted below and evaluate by ourselves how perverse is try to write code in Batch files! **`:/`**

Comment: This article perfectly expresses my opinion: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Stupid-Coding-Tricks-A-Batch-of-Pi.  I especially like the [Comments](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/comments/Stupid-Coding-Tricks-A-Batch-of-Pi) section. For example: "I am amazed and nauseated at the same time. Bravo."

Comment: @paulsm4 That depends on your point of view. Of course a script that calculates a float would be a convoluted mess in batch, as batch only handles integer math. Batch scripts work well where they work well, and are user friendly to distribute and execute. Citing an example of a script attempting to drive a bolt with a hammer is a poor argument. You wouldn't use Tk to enumerate a directory at the console, or 15 lines of C# to handle what a batch script can do in 5, just like you wouldn't use batch to listen for mouse events. Batch is not always right, but neither is it always wrong by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decimal to binary converter?

I see in your paste you're computing the binary result by comparing the entered number with powers of two.  There's a [more efficient algorithm](http://www.robotroom.com/NumberSystems3.html) for converting dec to bin, and it'll handle numbers from 0 to 2147483647.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

if "%~1"=="" (
    echo usage: %~nx0 integer
    goto :EOF
)

set /a dec = %~1

:/2
set /a mod = dec %% 2, dec /= 2
set "bin=%mod%%bin%"
if %dec% gtr 0 goto :/2

echo %bin%
```

I also see paulsm4's comment recommending another *(suspicious quote)* "real" language.  Truthfully, though, not counting languages that already have a direct int-to-bin conversion method, the batch scripting language can actually save you a few steps because all math is integer math, with decimals inherently truncated.  This saves you from having to `Math.floor` or similar on every iteration.  This is one situation where batch is better-suited for the task than many other languages.

---

If you prefer to do the power-of-two comparison method, here's another solution.  It loops 31 times regardless of the length of the numeral you supply, but `for /L` is very efficient.  This may actually be faster than the method above for larger numbers for many iterations.  Not sure.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1"=="" (
    echo usage: %~nx0 integer
    goto :EOF
)

set /a dec = %~1, pow = 1073741824

for /L %%I in (1,1,31) do (
    if !dec! geq !pow! (
        set "bin=!bin!1"
        set /a dec -= pow
    ) else (
        if defined bin set "bin=!bin!0"
    )
    set /a pow /= 2
)

if not defined bin set bin=0
echo %bin%
```

---

And just because I felt like it, here's the same thing but using bitwise operations.  **This is the most efficient method.**  *(Edit: or at least it was, until [Aacini posted his solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31776959/1683264).)*

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1"=="" (
    echo usage: %~nx0 integer
    goto :EOF
)

for /L %%I in (0,1,30) do (
    set /a "mask = 1 << %%I, bit = ^!^!(%~1 & mask)"
    if !mask! gtr %~1 goto break
    set "bin=!bit!!bin!"
)
:break

if not defined bin set bin=0
echo %bin%
```

---

**Efficiency:**

I ran a series of tests to determine which method is most efficient.  For each method, I sent the output to NUL, looped the script for 1000 iterations, then took an average of the run times over 3 runnings.  I did this first with a small value of 5, then a large value of 2147483646.  **Results:**

> - goto method, input=small: **7.37 seconds**
> - goto method, input=large: **33.77 seconds**
> - powers-of-two method, input=small: **8.38 seconds**
> - powers-of-two method, input=large: **12.44 seconds**
> - bitwise method, input=small: **6.35 seconds**
> - bitwise method, input=large: **11.42 seconds**

These results are not surprising, as `for /L` is generally faster than a `goto` loop, and bitwise operations occur faster than integer math.

Comment: I still believe .bat files are inappropriate for any tasks more sophisticated than "start", "copy" or "del".  I still strongly encourage the OP to learn a "real" language.  But +1: I applaud your ingenuity!  PS: I wish we could award extra points for the performance analysis.  Great job!

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete rojo's answer, I think that [this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4757&p=27485#p27485) is the most efficient method to convert a decimal number to binary:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%~1"=="" (
    echo usage: %~nx0 integer
    goto :EOF
)

set "decimal=%~1"
set "binary="
for /L %%i in (1,1,32) do (
   set /A "bit=decimal&1, decimal>>=1"
   set "binary=!bit!!binary!"
   if !decimal! equ 0 goto break
)
:break
echo %binary%
```

Note that previous method correctly convert *negative numbers*!

At [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4022&p=22370#p22370) there is a Batch file that can convert *very large* decimal numbers to binary. The result is stored in a Batch variable, so the binary number may have a maximum of 8 K digits. This means that the maximum decimal number that can be converted is `2^8192 - 1`.